# Why is Writer monad defined as WriterT in scalaz?

Tags: monads, scalaz, monad-transformers

I noticed that some monads, e.g. `Writer`, are defined in `scalaz` as *monad transformers* of `Identity` monad. Why is that ?

Comment: Identity does nothing, `flatMap` is just a function application and using it in transformers just gives you original functionality of a monad. So, e.g Writer is isomorphic to WriterT[Id], and Reader is just a Kleisli[Id]

Comment: @AlexIv Thank you. It makes sense. I did not get it entirely but I will think it over.